# How to delete record on EOS if I forget table structure

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, table

I issue an EOS token for fun half a year ago and I'm planning to release my EOS ram recently.

The problem is that I forget the table structure I made before and I overwrite the contract and there is no ABI left.

How can I figure out the table structure or delete the records in this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you forgot that, checkout your history setabi action from block explorer, e.g. eosq.app, and you will get the binanry abi.

You can either parse the abi binary to readable json, or just construct the setabi transaction and push it to the mainnet, then use command cleos get abi to see your abi.